# Any way to synchronize calendar app across Android and iOS?

Tags: sync, calendar, google-calendar, ios

Me and my partner have been searching for ages for a calendar application that will sync across both Android and iOS devices (as she has an iPhone). We would love to be able to see each others calendars but can't find an app anywhere which will let us do this effectively?

Anybody know of any?

Comment: You mean you like to sync your and your partners calender events?

Comment: @vini yeah that's exactly what I mean

Comment: Ok - I've found a nice article which solves it...

http://www.itguyfixit.com/2010/09/how-to-sync-google-shared-calendars.html

Comment: @Rich would you mind to answer your own question with an excerpt of the mentioned article, including the link and your own comments -- and then later (in 2+ days, when that option appears) accept this answer? That makes it easier for other "searchers" to recognize your question as having a solution. Moreover, it preserves the content in case the linked page disappears. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an Android problem, *per se*.

My wife and I have been effectively sharing our calendars for a few years. I use Android, she uses an iPhone.

The secret sauce is to use [Google Calendar](https://www.google.com/calendar).

- We each have our own Google Accounts, and have shared (read-access) with each other.
- We also have created shared calendars for both of our kids, Household events (e.g., when is the trash picked up), Local events we might want to attend, and the schedule for their schools

Getting the calendar(s) into Android is academic (and I just use the standard Calendar app). She simply needed to connect her calendar app. (She is having a problem where sometimes events she creates on her device don't show up, but that's an iPhone issue.)